# Mathematica 11.1 GUI flickers on linux

Tags: front-end, linux

Everything in the Mathematica window flickers. This includes the menus and all dialog boxes. I tried reading up on this but found nothing. The only thing I know is that Mathematica GUI runs on the Qt framework. If it is an issue with Qt, then how do I fix it?

Edit 1: Mathematica version 11.1.1.0

3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca
Release:    17.1
Codename:   rebecca

Comment: Whenever something weird is happening I always start by suggesting [a clean restart](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). It's easy enough to do that it's worth a try, but it probably won't solve your problem in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @N.J.Evans I tried cleanstart. It doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: For questions like this, it is useful to provide as many details about your system as possible (i.e. full M version: 11.1.0 or 11.1.1? Linux distro and version; any hardware you consider relevant; and special modifications you may have done to your system; was it fine before or does it flicker since first installation?)

Comment: @Szabolcs I have added details to the question. No problems in the system prior to or after install, except the Mathematica window flickering

Comment: It's probably the default wayland setting. I encountered similar problem before. You can try to disable it and see how things go.

Comment: @Turgon could you tell me how to disable the default wayland setting?

Comment: I set WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm/custom.conf but my distro is Fedora so I'm not sure that can work on Ubuntu.