# All possible cases of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume that I have two number $a$ and $b$ and an $n \times n$ matrix. How can I write code which can compute all determinants of the matrices with entries $a$ or $b$. In other words, I want to see the determinant of all $2^{n^{2}}$ matrices with entries $a$ and $b$.

Comment: A short example with a Mathematica code would be helpful for understanding the problem. At least show what you have tried.

Comment: Do you need the multiplicity of each possible determinant value?

Comment: A.Mpi, please see  Michael E2's comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154715/125) which is our community's standard welcome message to new users.

Answer (score 8):

```
n = 3; 
matrices = Tuples[{a, b}, {n, n}];
Length@matrices
```

> 512

```
Det /@ matrices // Simplify // Short
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-a (a-b)^2, -a (a-b)^2, a (a-b)^2, <<486>>, (a-b)^2 b, -(a-b)^2 b, -(a-b)^2 b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
Det /@ matrices // Simplify // Tally // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]